# NestJS DTO class set class-validator and class-transformer execution order

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator, class-validator, class-transformer

Is there a way to set the **execution order of decorators** when describing a DTO class in NestJS using `class-validator` and `class-transformer` packages?

Following code fails when the value of `foo` is set to `null` with the error:

> Expected a string but received a null

```js
@IsOptional()
@IsString()
@IsByteLength(1, 2048)
@Transform(({ value }) => validator.trim(value))
@Transform(({ value }) => validator.stripLow(value))
foo: string;
```

Even tho I have a `isString` decorator that should check that indeed a string was passed and must already fail to not pass the execution to the `@Transform` decorators, but it didn't failed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Class-Validator works based on classes. Request payloads that come into the server are just plain JSON objects to start off with. To change this behaviour, Nest has to first call `plainToClass` from `class-validator` if you're using its `ValidationPipe`. Because of this, the `@Transform()` decorators take precedence over the other class-validator decorators, and are acted upon first. You could get around this by using multiple pipes, or possibly providing default values for the `@Transform()` decorator, but what is happening is the intended effect.

Answer (score 6):

Control @Transfrom and Validator Decorator execution order by 2 ValidationPipe

main.ts

```js
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),

    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: { groups: ['transform'] },
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(4000);
}
bootstrap();
```

create-user.dto.ts

```js
export class CreateUserDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'username',
    minLength: 4,
    maxLength: 64,
  })
  @Length(4, 64)
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'password',
    minLength: 4,
    maxLength: 64,
  })
  @Length(6, 64)
  @Transform(({ value }: { value: string }) => hashSync(value), {
    groups: ['transform'],
  })
  password: string;
}
```

This will run @Length first, and then @Transform.

Translation with Deepl

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue using this approach

if in transform code throw the issue, I handle it and return `undefined`.  In validation fn I can check if it undefined and return error message

```
   class GetGeneratorDto {  
    @IsStringDOM({
        message: 'Не был переданблок',
    })
    @Transform(({ value }) => {
        try {
            return cheerio.load(value);
        } catch {}
    })
    blockContent: cheerio.CheerioAPI;
}
```

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions } from 'class-validator';
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

export function IsStringDOM(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: any, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            name: 'isStringDOM',
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: {
                validate(value: cheerio.CheerioAPI) {
                    try {
                        const $ = value;

                        const recordType = Number(
                            $('[data-record-type]').attr('data-record-type'),
                        );

                        if (recordType !== 396) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    } catch (error) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
            },
        });
    };
}
```