# I am getting NestJS class validation error for IsString check

Tags: node.js, validation, nestjs, prisma

I have a nestjs setup where I created an api that takes query params to filter data. In one specific attribute, 'interior'. I am providing list of enums separated by string like 'api/endpoint?interior=FURNISHED,UNFURNISHED'

Using class validator, I am splitting them into arrays of string and matching them against 'Interior' enum. But I am getting "Must be a valid string error"

Below is my Interior enum that is part of prisma client

```
export const Interior: {
  FURNISHED: 'FURNISHED',
  SEMI_FURNISHED: 'SEMI_FURNISHED',
  UNFURNISHED: 'UNFURNISHED'
};
```

This is my Dto for query param

```
export class GetPropertiesQueryDto {
  @IsString({ message: 'Interior must be a valid string' })
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.split(','))
  @IsEnum(Interior, {
    each: true,
  })
  interior?: Interior[];
....
....
}
```

Now if I provide wrong enums like "each value in interior must be one of the following values: FURNISHED, SEMI_FURNISHED, UNFURNISHED"

But if I provide correct attribute, it fails on String check saying 'Interior must be a valid string'

What am I missing? Does type of attribute has to match that of IsString? IsString check passes if I supply wrong values, but fails if correct enums are provided

Answer (score 3):

With Nest's `ValidationPipe`, transformation happens before validation, because Nest needs to de-serialize the JSON into class instances for class-validator to work. So this string comes in, you transform it to an enum array, and then you are validating that it is a string, hence the error.

If it has it, add an `{ each: true }` property to the `@IsString()` so that it can validate each item in the array is a string, or just leave the validation portion to the enum.

Comment: Based on what you said, the order of decorators is not important, right?

Comment: Correct. Order only matters when decorators modify the descriptor. These apply metadata that is later read so they can be in any order

Comment: I had a similar issue - overall I treated a property as an Array in one decorator, and as a simple type in another one, which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

`IsString()` is called after `Transform()` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091136/7767387)), so `Transform()` covert value to array so to solve this you may validate each value.

```
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @IsEnum(Interior, { each: true })
  @IsString({ message: 'Interior must be a valid string', each: true })
  @Transform(({ value }) =>
    typeof value == 'string'
      ? value
          .split(',')
          .map((item) => item.trim())
          .map((type: Interior) => Interior[type])
      : value,
  )
  interior?: Interior[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my case. The transform decorator ran twice because of plain to class and class to plain transformation. In short, the transform decorator also ran again after splitting the string into an array. So the general solution, in this case, was to pass "toClassOnly" to true in the params of transform. That ensures that transform decore executes only once...

```
export class GetPropertiesQueryDto {
  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(
    ({ value }) => value.split(','),
    { toClassOnly: true }, // This is needed so that transform runs only once
  )
....
}
```

One thing I noticed thanks to Jay McDoniel that transform decore executes before any other validation check no matter the order. So I added IsArray() check instead of IsString() validation, as my final datatype is an array, not a string, and this validation check will be executed after the transformation.